# where condition doesn't work

Tags: php, mysqli

I've made an html design that have many checkbox and I want to take values of this checkbox and search for data similar for it in the database
the problem is in the query ...where condition isn't work although I've tested it in phpmyadmin and it was work.

```
 <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bella_vista");
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

      foreach ($_POST['Ingredient'] as $selected)
       {
//sql query to search db

$query ="select name,image
        from reciepe
        where R_ID =any(select I_ID FROM ingredient where item like '%$selected%') ";

$result =mysqli_query ($conn,$query);
          print_r ($result);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $name = $row['name'];
        $image = $row['image'];
        echo '<div>'.$name. ''.$image.'</div>';
     }
     }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Try this: `s/=any/in /`

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
$query ="select name,image
        from reciepe
        where R_ID =any(select I_ID FROM ingredient where item like '%$selected%') ";
```

To

```
$query ="SELCT name,image
        FROM reciepe
        WHERE R_ID IN (SELCT I_ID FROM ingredient WHERE item LIKE '%$selected%') ";
```

Comment: PLease check the result of `SELCT I_ID FROM ingredient WHERE item LIKE '%$selected%'` and please confirm that required `R_ID` is in the results.